# What can be said about $e_x(f)=f(x)$ in a group?

Tags: group-theory

This is a continuation of my previous question(linked below).

> Let $X$ be a set and $(G, \star)$ a group. We denote $G^X$ the set of a mappings from $X$ to $G$.
>   Show that $G^X$ has a group structure induced by $G$

[The proof lies here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434793/x-a-set-and-g-a-group-let-gx-be-the-set-of-mappings-from-x-to-g-sho)

Now I am asked:

> If $x \in X$, what can be said about this function that maps from $G^X$ to $G$  such that $e_x(f)=f(x)$?

And to be honest, I don't know what to say except that it seems to be a group homomorphism because $\forall f,g \in G^X$, $e_x(f \star g) = (f \star g )(x) \in G$ this $(f \star g)(x) = f(x) \star g(x)$. Is there anything else I could notice?

Comment: Yes, it's a group homomorphism, I think that's all you're supposed to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $e_x$ is a group homomorpism, like @QiaochuYuan suggests.

Completing your work, we have

$$\begin{align}
e_x(f \star g) &= (f \star g )(x) \\
&=f(x)\star g(x) \\
&=e_x(f)\star e_x(g).
\end{align}$$